# SQL for table creation incorrect when autogenerating using hibernate with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I decided to play with hibernate using annotations this weekend and have encountered an interesting issue which I'm hoping you all can help with.  The problem I am encountering is that the schema created is not correct when I attempt to use a ManyToOne relationship.

I have two classes of note.  A User class and a CourseTaken class.  The user can have any number of courses they have taken.  Code is below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_taken")
public class CourseTaken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "course_id", columnDefinition = "INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    ...getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<CourseTaken> coursesTaken = new HashSet<CourseTaken>();
    ...getters/setters
}
```

When I have hibernate generate the schema, here is the creation statement for the course_taken table:

```
create table course_taken (course_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT not null, courseID integer not null, user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, primary key (course_id))
```

Hibernate seems very confused by my attempt to use the `@OneToMany` annotation. Any ideas?

I have played with various configurations:
org.hibernate.dialect.

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5
```

I'm using maven, here are my hibernate pom dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Edited post and included my pom.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I must have had my dialect a little incorrect. The following seemed to fix the issue

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```